# Change apache MPM prefork to worker on Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, mod-wsgi

My project by default is running under Prefork MPM. Rigth now i am having some slowing issues, my web got timeout error. Searching on differents foroums i see that is recomended to use the worker module and i see differents ways to changed it but in the end nothing working with my project.

I run my project under apache2.2 with this script

*python manage.py runmodwsgi --setup-only --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000 --reload-on-changes **--server-root=/mod_wsgi/***

This script create my apachectl in the folder "mod_wsgi"
Inside the folder i use "./apachectl -V" to see the module that is working in the project and is see this

*Server version: Apache/2.2.34 (Unix)
Server built:   Nov  1 2017 18:47:16
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:43
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.1, APR-Util 1.4.1
Compiled using: APR 1.5.1, APR-Util 1.4.1
Architecture:   64-bit
**Server MPM:     Prefork**
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 **-D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"**
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
...*

So, to change it from prefork MPM to Worker i tried was uncomment line:
HTTPD=/usr/sbin/httpd.worker
in the file in this path /etc/sysconfig/httpd, then i restart and run it again, but didnt changed it.

Other thing that i saw in the web was change the file /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf but this path doesnt exitst in my instance.

Also i tried to run my initial script with this aditional flag **./configure --with-mpm=worker** but seems that is not working.

Aditional, and is a thing that im not complety sure why happend, if i put just "apachectl -V" without "./" i see that the MPM changed to worker but not in my apachectl from my mod_wsgi folder.

Some advice to change the MPM of my project?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

‘Restart’ is ambiguous (will likely translate to apachectl graceful or equivalent). When changing MPM be sure to stop then start.

Answer (score 0):

In your Amazon Linux AMI, you can change your MPM here - `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf`

Tip - You should consider using `worker` or `event` module instead of `prefork`.